# What does "Schmuck" mean in German?

Tags: translation, slang

I was on this jewerly website [Wempe](http://www.wempe.de/index.htm) and if you look they have a section titled **Schmuck**.

This is commonly known to mean [idiot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck_%28pejorative%29) here in the U.S. Everything I look up to see what it means says pretty much the same thing: Jerk, Moron, etc.

I don't see why they would have a line called schmuck unless there was an alternate meaning in German.

I **did** try to translate the page but since that text is actual an image, it does not get translated.

So in the German language does *schmuck* mean *moron*, or something else?

Comment: Geschmeide http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschmeide but not very common term imho

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you completely but "Schmuck" *is* the German word for "jewelery". Or is it something else you're wondering about?

Comment: The more interesting question is in my eyes, *how come "schmuck" is a pejorative term in (American) English?*

Comment: It's not a "line called schmuck". That entire page is in German. You are looking at a German word. So please look it up in a German dictionary of your choice. Or just switch to the English version of the site where everything is conveniently translated for you. In its current form, this is a non-question.

Comment: The issue is that "Schmuck" is a German-sounding word with a pejorative meaning in English. Then the question is, does the German "original" (or equivalent) have a similar, or entirely different meaning. That seems like a valid question to me. The answer uncovered a case of "false friends," and eliminated a source of confusion, not least for the answerer, a native speaker of German. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Tom I think that the negative sentiment comes from the fact that the OP looked up the word that he suspects to be German in several places, but not in a German-English dictionary.

Comment: The pejorative term which the OP probably meant is spelled _Schmock_ in German – _Schmuck_ is the just the English spelling. See [Wikipedia – Schmuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck_(pejorative)): "The German word Schmuck is unrelated and means 'jewelry, adornments'. In German the pejorative 'smuck' would be Schmock, closer to the original Yiddish word."

Comment: @John Isaacks I guess you do not see, that there are a number of votes to reopen your question. I think we generally find the problem interesting, but the formulation of your question needs improvement.

Comment: The question on the etymology of *"Schmuck"* in US-American English belongs to ELU and thus is off-topic for GLU. Any dictionary I consulted translated *Schmuck* correctly (e.g. Google Translate says: *jewelery jewelry decoration ornament adornment ornamentation embellishment array*).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you follow from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck_%28pejorative%29 to the German version, you will see that in German the word is spelled [Schmock](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmock), which is something completely different from [Schmuck](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmuck).

> schmuck = Schmock
>
> jewelry = Schmuck

It seems to be a case of a false friend. And let me add that I didn't know the word Schmock.

**Edit:**

@Takkat: Schmu seems to be a different word. See [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schmu) with equal meaning in [de.wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schmu).

And here you find a [List of English words of Yiddish origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Yiddish_origin).

Comment: You can still hear "Was für ein Schmock!" or "Was will denn der Schmock da?" in Frankfurt and around. There is an interesting online newspaper article about this word https://www.juedische-allgemeine.de/kultur/journalisten-und-andere-schmocks/ (in German!).

Answer (score 2):

schmuck = hübsch = pretty
Schmuck = something that makes you pretty

Answer (score 1):

Schmuck is a Yiddish (mix of High German [and other tongues such as Slavic] and Hebrew) word that is a pejorative which can mean idiot but more commonly it is calling someone "the male genitalia" when I was growing up on the Lower East Side of NYC.  While not Jewish myself, many caught on to the use of Yiddish.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, as you can address the male parts jokingly as "Kronjuwelen" etc...

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmock

Comment: But is isn't the Yiddish word here!